# How to integrate Google Pay library into website?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, requirejs, requirejs-config.js, googlepay

I'm trying to integrate Google Pay into my Cart page. But, I always get an error, it looks like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for "https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js" https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at makeError (require.js:168:17)
at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)
```

The steps i did:

- define path in requirejs-config.js
  [image]
- inject component in template
  [image]
- component's content:
  [image]

How can I fix it?
Any of your comments will be very helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: :(( does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's so strange :((